# .INI Files - Change Strings Only - (Notepad++ Regex Replace)

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++, ini

I have about 100 .ini files to alter. I need to change only the number of " (double quote marks) around string values. For example:

Change:

```
[GROUP]
AnyWord1="StR1Ng?!,''.-<br/>"
AnyWord2="["Don''t change these quotes either",13401.8,0]"
AnyWord3="42"
AnyWord4="Another String"
AnyWord5="Another String"
```

Into:

```
[GROUP]
AnyWord1=""StR1Ng?!,''.-<br/>""
AnyWord2="["Don''t change these quotes either",13401.8,0]"
AnyWord3="42"
AnyWord4=""Another String""
AnyWord5=""Another String""
```

I think this can be done with Notepad++ Replace with RegEx, but I can't make it work.

So far I have this, which will select the required lines, as long as there are no strings which begin with a number:

^([a-zA-Z0-9])+(=)(")([^(0-9)[])([^"]*)(")

Comment: How do you know to leave AnyWord2 alone?

Comment: Hi, I've done some testing with the tool I'm using, and for some reason it thinks about these two strings differently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a code or regex writing service. We're glad to try and help, but we expect you to make some effort to solve the problem yourself first. What efforts have you made at writing a regex to do what you're asking, and how did it not work as you'd expect? How do you expect the regex to differentiate between the ones you want to remove and the ones you don't? (And *I've tested and the tool doesn't like it when I remove this set* isn't useful to an executing regex; you'll need to do much better than that for us.)

Comment: @MWK "for some reason" isn't actually helpful.

Comment: This is the tool I'm building .INI files for: https://forums.bistudio.com/forums/topic/186131-inidbi2-save-and-load-data-to-the-server-or-your-local-computer-without-databases/ They are just used as text files. I didn't see how it was relevant sorry. This tool works with a video game. Once the variable type is determined, the tool deals with the array as the game does. The game only needs single double quotes, whereas, the tool developer has chosen to read in strings with 2 double quotes.

Comment: Would either of you be able to improve on my solution? I do have strings that begin with numbers. Not many, so no big deal if not. I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
^(?<varname>([a-zA-Z0-9])+)(=)(")(?<val>([^(0-9)[])([^"\r\n]*))(")
```

Replace with:

```
$+{varname}=""$+{val}""
```

All strings must not begin with a number though.